# Why is it difficult (and not precise) to compute the rank of large matrix numerically?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I have a general question.
I have a large square matrix ($n> 1000$) and it is needed to compute the rank of this matrix. I am reading that the computation of the rank for large matrices, can make numerical problems and the result is not reliable.
My question is: Is this correct? And if yes, can you tell me shortly why it is so? And can anyone introduce me some literature which this issue is adressed there?

Thanks in advance,
Reza

Comment: The normal tool to do something like you are suggesting is the singular value decomposition.  Problems arise in floating point arithmetic because rank deficient matrices can be arbitrarily close to full rank ones.  Speaking loosely, they can be so close that a computer using floating point arithmetic can't tell them apart.

Comment: one reason is that the matrices nearly never have integer entries, and that a small error in the way you store the numbers (floating points...) nearly always transforms a singular matrix into an inversible one. (this is because inversible matrices are denses in the set of (square) matrices)

Comment: currently battling this, I have a set of points I am trying to determine their coplanarity by getting the rank of the matrix of their relative differences, with all points rounded off to integer values the rank is 2 as expected but without being rounded off the rank is 3